# Orangescrum stuck at database configuration: Wrong database information. Please try with correct information

Tags: xampp

I trying orangescrum in a localhost using xampp and after following the installation step according to their site, Im stuck with this page

[image]

I double check every details in database.php and use the same credential in very field but still get the error.

For your kind assistance,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the database credentials & information provided during the database setup, this should not show you. However, if you're facing the same issue, can you please connect with us on live chat or email us support[at]orangescrum.com.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in MySQL with root privilege.

Replace username and password with appropriate values.

**ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';**